# Windows 7 Registry editor is not opening

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I ran **regedit.exe** by Administrator, but nothing happens even no error message.

> "Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator"

is not my case. I checked **mpedit.msc** and that option was "Not Configured" from the first time.

I googled and type this command on cmd but doesn't work.

> reg add
>   "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /t
>   Reg_dword /v DisableRegistryTools /f /d 0

I Also did it in "safe mode" and still same.

My anti-virus solutions maintains the lastest update all the time and showed the result **not infected(0)**.

I don't even guess what's going on my pc..

Comment: What account do you use to login and what antivirus ? Usually this is how a virus acts: it disables access to your registry.

Comment: My account named after me and it belongs to Admistrator Group. My antivirus is 'Ahnlab v3 Lite'. Really appreciate if you recommand any free security solutions.

Comment: I use Avast.  I love it.  They have a few tiers, plus a free one that works great.

Comment: Make a copy of `regedit.exe`, e.g. to `regedit_2.exe` and try to start from this copy. You find it in folder `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: Wernfried// I tried your suggestion but still nothing happened. Think I should do a Deep content inspection with Avast or something. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: I did a full Virus search with Avast Free version, got a result of 2 virus(malware or whatever..) and cured it! But still cannot open registry editor.. Sad

Comment: I had no choice, installed a third-party Registry Editor and finally could make it :(